# Using extend to add a count column in Azure Stream Analytics/Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I have an Application Insights Azure Stream Analytics query that looks like this...

```
requests
| summarize count() by bin(duration, 1000)
| order by duration asc nulls last
```

...which gives me something like this, which shows the number of requests binned by duration in seconds, recorded in Application Insights.

```
| 0    | 1000 |
| 1000 | 500  |
| 2000 | 200  |
```

I would like to able to add another column which shows the count of exceptions from all requests in each bin.

I understand that `extend` is used to add additional columns, but to do so I would have to reference the 'outer' expression to get the bin constraints, which I don't know how to do. Is this the best way to do this? Or am I better off trying to `join` the two tables together and then doing the `summarize`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

As you suspected - `extend` will not help you much here. You need is to run  `join kind=leftouter` on the operation IDs (`leftouter` is needed so you won't drop requests that did not have any exceptions):

```
requests
| join kind=leftouter (
    exceptions
    | summarize exceptionsCount = count() by operation_Id
) on operation_Id
| summarize count(), sum(exceptionsCount) by bin(duration, 1000)
| order by duration asc nulls last
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you!